# Recover a surface's equation from its curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, differential

Can the equation of a surface in Euclidean 3 space be recovered from the equation of its Gaussian curvature?

Comment: Consider than the cylinder and plane both have zero Gaussian curvature.

Comment: Please have a look to the fundamental theorem of surface. If you have first and second fundamental form coefficient which satisfy the Cordazzi equations and $EG-F^2>0$ , then there esists a parametrization of a regular orientable surface that admits the first and second fundamental forms previously specified.